# Most efficient method of finding the number of common factors of two numbers

Tags: go, math

**I have two numbers for example the numbers are 12 and 16.**

> factors of 12 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12
>
> factors of 16 are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16
>
> common factors of these two numbers are 1, 2 and 4.

So the number of common factors are 3. I need to build a Go program for finding the number common factors of two numbers. But the program should be efficient and with minimum number of loops or without loops.
I will provide my code and you can also contribute and suggest with another best methods.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var (
    fs    []int64
    fd    []int64
    count int
)

func main() {
    commonFactor(16, 12)
    commonFactor(5, 10)
}

func commonFactor(num ...int64) {
    count = 0
    if num[0] < 1 || num[1] < 1 {
        fmt.Println("\nFactors not computed")
        return
    }
    for _, val := range num {
        fs = make([]int64, 1)
        fmt.Printf("\nFactors of %d: ", val)
        fs[0] = 1
        apf := func(p int64, e int) {
            n := len(fs)
            for i, pp := 0, p; i < e; i, pp = i+1, pp*p {
                for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
                    fs = append(fs, fs[j]*pp)
                }
            }
        }
        e := 0
        for ; val&1 == 0; e++ {
            val >>= 1
        }
        apf(2, e)
        for d := int64(3); val > 1; d += 2 {
            if d*d > val {
                d = val
            }
            for e = 0; val%d == 0; e++ {
                val /= d
            }
            if e > 0 {
                apf(d, e)
            }
        }
        if fd == nil {
            fd = fs
        }
        fmt.Println(fs)
    }
    for _, i := range fs {
        for _, j := range fd {
            if i == j {
                count++
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Number of common factors =", count)
}
```

Output is :

> Factors of 16: [1 2 4 8 16] Factors of 12: [1 2 4 3 6 12]
>
> Number of common factors = 3
>
> Factors of 5: [1 5] Factors of 10: [1 2 5 10]
>
> Number of common factors = 2

[Goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/7k7m1aG8ZE0)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter, or where are you trying to improve performance?

Comment: @Flimzy I just elaborated my question and check it out now.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I am not get strucked during coding but my intension is to find better and efficient methods

Comment: That's a step in the right direction. What, specifically, are you hoping to improve? Why do you believe it performs poorly?

Comment: @filmzy I got this problem during one of a coding competition and they asked to solve it using less number of loops. I hope you guys understand.In my code u guys can see so many nested loops and I think it is not a good practice. So I need better suggestions from the community side

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya please check the code and playground link I provided.

Comment: @ASHWINRAJEEV https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8611/number-of-common-divisors-between-two-given-numbers

Comment: @RoryDaulton numbers can be in the range (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807). Please check my code I use int64.

Comment: I see that those are the *possible* numbers. But if you want to program for efficiency, you need to know the range of *expected* numbers--i.e. the numbers for which you want your program to be efficient. One algorithm works well for small numbers, another for intermediate numbers (around 32 bits), another for large (around 64 bits). The latter requires very sophisticated mathematics.

Comment: One last question from me. Your title and your description ask only to find the number of common factors. But your example input shows much more: a list of the factors of each number and a list of the common factors. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @RoryDaulton please encourage questioning and don't think like a pro. My question is simple to understand and you can implement it using whatever method you know it is a field for knowledge sharing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1, with no loops just recursion

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func factors(n int, t int, res *[]int) *[]int {
    if t != 0 {
        if (n/t)*t == n {
            temp := append(*res, t)
            res = &temp
        }
        res = factors(n, t-1, res)
    }
    return res
}

func cf(l1 []int, l2 []int, res *[]int) *[]int {
    if len(l1) > 0 && len(l2) > 0 {
        v1 := l1[0]
        v2 := l2[0]
        if v1 == v2 {
            temp := append(*res, v1)
            res = &temp
            l2 = l2[1:]
        }
        if v2 > v1 {
            l2 = l2[1:]
        } else {
            l1 = l1[1:]
        }
        res = cf(l1, l2, res)
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    n, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    n2, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("give a number")
        panic(err)
    }
    factorlist1 := factors(n, n, &[]int{})
    factorlist2 := factors(n2, n2, &[]int{})
    fmt.Printf("factors of %d %v\n", n, factorlist1)
    fmt.Printf("factors of %d %v\n", n2, factorlist2)
    common := cf(*factorlist1, *factorlist2, &[]int{})
    fmt.Printf("number of common factors = %d\n", len(*common))

}
```

However, this blows up with larger numbers such as 42512703

replacing the func that do the work with iterative versions can cope with bigger numbers

```
func factors(n int) []int {
        res := []int{}
        for t := n; t > 0; t-- {
                if (n/t)*t == n {
                        res = append(res, t)
                }
        }
        return res
}

func cf(l1 []int, l2 []int) []int {
        res := []int{}
        for len(l1) > 0 && len(l2) > 0 {
                v1 := l1[0]
                v2 := l2[0]
                if v1 == v2 {
                        res = append(res, v1)
                        l2 = l2[1:]
                }
                if v2 > v1 {
                        l2 = l2[1:]
                } else {
                        l1 = l1[1:]
                }
        }
        return res
}
```

Comment: Good code recursion method is nice. Can you please add a go playground link also

Answer (score 0):

func Divisors(n int)int{

```
prev := []int{}

for i := n;i > 0;i--{
    prev = append(prev,i)
}

var res int

for j := prev[0];j > 0;j--{
    if n % j == 0 {
        res++
    }
}

return res
```

}